# python3: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have a problem statement where i have to fill the missing values in
a specified format. Like Below

```
Input1: "_,_,_,24" [24/4] Output1: 6,6,6,6
Input2: "40,_,_,_,60"[40+60/5] Output2: 20,20,20,20,20
Input3: "80,_,_,_,_". [80/5] Output3: 16,16,16,16,16
```

My code is as below

```
import numpy as np



def curve_smoothing(s):
    s1=s.split(",")
    s2=len(s1)
    s3=s2-1
    r=[]
    
    
    for j in s1:
        if j.isdigit():
            r.append(int(j))
        else:
            r.append(0)
    print(r)       
            
    avg=int(np.mean(r))
    
    if (r[0]==0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]==0):
        w=(list(map(lambda x: avg,r))) 

        
    return w        
  
    
    
s="_,_,_,24"    
z=curve_smoothing(s)
print(z)
```

For this I am getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced
before assignment.

can someone help me out rectifying it?

Comment: It means it did not go inside your if block, so w is not defined.

Comment: Do not use `&` and `|` for booleans.  In Python, you use the words `and` and `or` for this.

Comment: Adding on to what the above comment says, please don't name your variables `s`, `z`, `r`, and `w`. Use `snake_case` in order to actually describe what the variable contains.

Comment: The if statement is False so w does not get assigned. You need to assign a value to w in the case that the if statement is False

Comment: *if you are getting an error* **always** post the *full error message **including the stack trace***

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is saying exactly what is wrong. You are using `w` in the `if` statement before you ever initialized it. To fix the error, just do something like this:

```py
# ... snip ...

def curve_smoothing(s):
    # ... snip ...
    avg = int(np.mean(r))

    w = []
    if (r[0]==0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]==0):
        # ... snip ...
```

*Note that I put `# ... snip ...` in order to break up the code to show where you need to add the new line.*

However, there are still a few problems with this code:

- Don't use `&` or `|` in Python - instead, use `and` and `or`. (@TimRoberts originally posted in comments)
- Use `snake_case` instead of naming your variables `s`, `z`, `r`, and `w`, in order to show what the variable contains and does
- *(This is opinion based)* You should format your code to improve visibility, such as adding spaces between your comparisons, adding comments, and reducing that big `if` statement in the body of your function into 3 variables.
- Either remove `s2` and `s3` and inline them into the actual statements or use the `snake_case` naming system to describe what they show.
- Why are you running `int(j)` if you know `j` is a digit?

Answer (score 0):

```
w = []
if (r[0]==0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]!=0) | (r[0]!=0 & r[s3]==0):
    w=(list(map(lambda x: avg,r)))
```

add a line define w, outside the if statement.